# Unable to put colors for LS by LS_OPTIONS

Tags: bash, ls

I find out that you can have the following for Grep in .bashrc

```
 # puts colors for all grep commands
 export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
```

I did not manage to get the similar command for LS_OPTIONS to work.

**Is there any other way than the following to give colors for your ls -command?**

```
alias ls='ls -Gh'
```

Comment: Now that I think about this, this really isn't a programming question is it?

Comment: My **ls** from Debian Squeeze also ignore **GREP_OPTIONS**. To work around I define alias in Bash: **alias ls='ls --color'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete solution:

```
# BSD ls
export LSCOLOR='exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad'
# GNU ls and others (for example, tree)
export LS_COLORS='di=34;40:ln=35;40:so=32;40:pi=33;40:ex=31;40:bd=34;46:cd=34;43:su=0;41:sg=0;46:tw=0;42:ow=0;43:'

if [ "$(uname -s)" = 'Linux' ]; then
  # GNU ls
  alias ls='ls --color=auto'
else
  # Assume BSD ls
  alias ls='ls -G'
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

For ls with colors to work you must do the following:

```
alias ls='ls -G'
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxCxDxBxegedabagacad
export TERM=xterm-color
```

Comment: This only applies to the BSD version of ls, which you would find on a Mac. On most Linux systems, the -G option means something else, and ls supports --color instead.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, aliasing `ls` with explicit options accomplishes what you want. If, however, you are especially keen on actually using the environment variable LS_OPTIONS, well, you still need an alias: `alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS '`

You would set LS_OPTIONS to any string of valid command-line options for `ls`. Run `ls --help` or `man ls` on the command-line to see what options are available. On my Linux system (openSuSE 42.2), with GNU `ls` v8.25, you would get coloured output by adding the option `--color=auto`.

So you would put the following in your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc file:

```
export LS_OPTIONS="--color=auto"
alias ls="ls $LS_OPTIONS "
```

To add additional options to the environment variable or the alias, just add them (separated by spaces) inside the double-quotes.

Comment: What can be inside the variable `$LS_OPTIONS`? Can you please relate your answer to existing answers.